# flutter cocoapods error while installing flutter

Tags: flutter

When I enter the 'sudo gem install cocoapods' command, I see 'Error installing cocoapods: The last version of activesupport (>= 5.0, < 8) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 6.1.7.6. Try installing it with `gem install activesupport -v 6.1.7.6` and then running the current command again activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.7.0. The current ruby ​​version is 2.6.10.210.' error pops up, I couldn't find the solution

I tried updating Ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resolve this issue by upgrading your Ruby version. Here's how you can do it using rbenv, a popular Ruby version management tool:

1. First, update rbenv and the ruby-build plugin:

   *brew update*

   *brew upgrade rbenv ruby-build*
2. Install the latest stable version of Ruby:

   *rbenv install 3.3.0*
3. Set the newly installed version as the global default:

   *rbenv global 3.3.0*
4. Verify that the correct version is being used:

   *ruby -v*

After upgrading Ruby, you should be able to install `cocoapods` without encountering the activesupport error.